# Exactly Who or What Assembles Transactions into Blocks?

Tags: block

Users broadcast transactions into the network.  Miners find and compete to validate blocks created every ten minutes by combining transactions.  Who or what assembles the transactions into blocks every ten minutes?

Related: Setting the required number of leading 0s for the winning hash throttles the speed at which blocks, and therefore transactions, are validated.  Who adjusts that number?

Answer (score 0):

> Who or what assembles the transactions into blocks every ten minutes?

Miners do. They do this before they attempt to find a block solution. It's the reason that miners exist.

> Setting the required number of leading 0s for the winning hash throttles the speed at which blocks, and therefore transactions, are validated. Who adjusts that number?

The protocol [defines](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/how-is-difficulty-calculated) how it should change. Each node works out the current difficulty independently, and each of them comes up with the same answer.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thank you for the answer.  I can see how the system works with Miners free to create their own blocks.  Not intuitively obvious but understandable  now I know for sure  that's how it works.  And thanks for the link to the rule on the  number of zeros. That explains a lot.  glb

Answer (score 0):

> Who or what assembles the transactions into blocks every ten minutes?

Maybe this is also what you are wondering about: [**How are transactions included into blocks?**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37191/transaction-inclusion-into-block)

Comment: For future reference: when you notice that a question has already been answered, it's best to use the "flag" button to indicate it is a duplicate, instead of posting an answer. This helps keep all the relevant information in one place.